# How do i configure my .vimrc File so That i press a key combo and it pasts lines of text which is situated at a fixed location on my computer

Tags: vim

I am a competitive programmer and I need to copy my Template from my coding library to the file I am currently working at.Right now I know how to use vim efficiently vim. For editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for the `:r[ead] <file>` command which reads in a file and inserts it at your cursor.

As an example, the following would bind normal mode `x` to the functionality which you described.

```
nmap x :r /path/to/file<CR>
```

Comment: I'd add: `:h template` and there exist many template and snippet plugins around there.